# Hide internal parameters from Spring interface for Swagger UI

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have an folowing endpoint:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/home", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public Mono<String> getData(ServerWebExchange exchange) { return Mono.empty(); }
```

The ServerWebExchange object is implemented in org.springframework.web.server. 
When I run it, in Swagger all the getters objects are shown. While I only need the body (I want to hide the reqest and the respone objects).

Tried to use

```
.ignoredParameterTypes(Principal.class, ServerHttpRequest.class, ServerHttpResponse.class)
```

But, it didn't had any effect.
Is there a way to hide those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

1. Disable the SeverWebExchange interface for swagger
2. Configure require input.

   ```
   @PostMapping(value = "/home", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
   @ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Body Params", paramType = "body")
   })
    public Mono<String> getData(
        @ApiIgnore ServerWebExchange exchange
    ) {
        return Mono.empty();
    }
   ```